# how to POST raw json using retrofit2 android java

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I am trying to post raw json like this:

```
[
{
"name":"a",
"id":"1"
},
{
"name":"b",
"id":"2"
]
```

it is work fine with postman but in retrofit it's add single value to the db
I tried to use this code:

```
public class DataModel{
...
}

@POST
Call<Void> addData(@Body List<DataModel>);
```

Comment: There is no code in the question

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to add a Wrapper to contain your list elements. Something like

```
class DataModelDTO {
    private List<DataModel> dataModels;
}
```

Using that wrapper, the elements list will be correctly mapped